# How much does UICollectionView load in memory?

Tags: ios, swift, image, uicollectionview, video-streaming

I have a UICollectionView that is filled with images, videos, and sound bytes. Everything is working great! I am however, concerned about bandwidth usage.

I am uncertain exactly how UICollectionView with dequeued-reusable cells work, in regards to when these items will be downloaded from storage.

Let's say I have this simple cell.

```
selfieCell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: message.stringOrKey), completed: nil)
return selfieCell
```

For purposes of answering my question, lets say I have 100 of them in a collection view cell, and only 3 cells are shown at a time.

- Do *all* 100 images load when UICollectionView is loaded?
- Or does the UICollection view *wait* until the cell is about to be shown to set the image (and thus download the file?)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Only 3 cells are shown at a time

The loaded cells are only the visible ones when you scroll `cellForItemAt` is called and other cell is deququed from the ones who will hide at top same when you scroll up again

Also caching image like sdwebimage won't load it again from server when the relevant cell is shown again